# How to indent with option-right in command line org-mode on a Mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, org-mode

In standalone emacs versions OS X, e.g. Aquamacs or the official Emacs.app I can make a new item e.g.

```
* Title
* Subtitle (new item)
```

and then press option+right to indent to the sublevel

```
* Title
** Subtitle (new item)
```

However, in Apple Terminal this command has no effect and in iterm.app a 'C' is created instead of the indent

```
* Title
C* Subtitle (new item)
```

Note that my meta key is working. E.g. if I use option+Enter (M-Enter), I can create a new item

```
* Title
* Subtitle (new item)
* another new item created with option+Enter
```

What is going on here? This problem has been bugging me under Snow Leopard for years and now on Maverick it remains the same.

Comment: Check that you have `Use Option as Meta key` set in preferences / keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Juachano.  Use Option as Meta key is already set unfortunately.

Comment: To extend on this, I can use e.g. option+Enter (M-Enter) to create a new subitem. The intending is the only function that I have noticed to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer now. In Terminal go to Preferences -> Settings -> Keyboard

If you find the combination 'option + right' delete that entry as it assigns the shortcut to another action.

In iTerm I couldn't find any shortcuts assigned to this shortcut, so still not sure what's causing the problem there.